# Write Permission to Schedule Reports in SSRS Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to set up the scheduler for reports in SSRS.

I currently have read access to query the 
database needed but I now need write permission to develop
and schedule reports according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-report-server-create-a-native-mode-report-server-database) article.

What's the *minimum* database write permission that would allow me
to run and schedule reports in SSRS?  I am using read 
access just for using SSRS and not for any DBA work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You* don't need any database permissions to set up a schedule.

First, your SSRS reports live in the Report Server database specified in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager. If SSRS did not have write access to it's own Report Server database, you would not be able to create reports or any other content.

You are probably accessing another database with customer data with read only access. You do not need write access to this database to create schedules.

SSRS accesses the report server database via the account configured as a Service Account in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

You will have to have your user granted the necessary permissions in SSRS in order to create and modify schedules. You can configure that by clicking the gear at the top right. If you are in the Administrators group on the local machine you will have full admin rights to the SSRS portal (that is the BUILTIN\Administrators role and it will override any permissions set in SSRS).

Schedules execute via the SQL Server Agent on the SSRS SQL Server. Your service account should be able to create and execute jobs via SQL Server Agent.

If all of this is set up right and you're getting a specific error trying to create schedules, I encourage you to post that information.